# How to change default value of page-size in bootstrap table?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I am using this bootstrap table 
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#client-side-pagination-table

which gives default page-size of 10. How can I change it to 5 or anything when the grid is loaded.

It gives option of selecting it `data-page-list="[5,10]"` but by default on load it keeps it 10.

Comment: Simply add data-page-size='25' to your <table>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use page `pageSize` property of `bootstrap table` like

```
$('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
                cache: false,
                height: 400,
                striped: true,
                pagination: true,
                pageSize: 5, //specify 5 here
                pageList: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200]//list can be specified here
});
```

Read **[Docs](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)**

Comment: the docs have moved: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

Comment: @ThePhi Updated the links..  Thank you so much.. :)

Comment: Simply add `data-page-size='25'` to your <table>

Answer (score 4):

with html only, use `data-page-size=5` :
http://jsfiddle.net/ThePhi/pamsqcea/

Answer (score 4):

You can use data-page-size="PAGE_SIZE" attribute in table tag. 
for eg.

```
<table class="table table-hover text-center" id="table" data-height="400" data-show-columns="true" data-toggle="table" data-search="true" data-show-export="true" data-pagination="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-page-size="50" data-show-columns="true"> 
          <thead>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
</table>
```

---